# Permissibility of earning from dealing in things that can be used for haram deeds?

Tags: halal-haram, business

I want to know about making/selling/dealing in things that have a possibility for haram use.

- If I sell vehicles with an audio system with an intention that the driver will use it to listen to directions, Qur'an, news on the radio, etc., will I be committing sin if the driver listen to songs and music on the audio system? What if I sell the vehicle on such a contract that the audio system should be used a per Shariah?
- If I develop software/photographs/any other digital data for halal purposes only and release it into the public domain (no copyrights reserved), and there is a possibility of haram use, though not intended by me, will I sin if someone uses the public domain data for haram? For example, uploading images and editing articles in Wikipedia requires the data to at least adhere to this license: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/.

Comment: If you give me grapes, and I turn them into wine, will you be responsible in front of Allah, for what **I** did with them, for **my** actions? Absolutely not. This answers both of your cases.

Answer (score 1):

> Narrated 'Umar bin Al-Khattab: I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying,
>   "The reward of deeds depends upon the intentions and every person will
>   get the reward according to what he has intended. So whoever emigrated
>   for worldly benefits or for a woman to marry, his emigration was for
>   what he emigrated for."([Sahih Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/1/1))

You will be held accountable for your intention, if you make something Halal with the intention for good use, then you will get it's reward. vice-versa

> "...No person earns any (sin) except against himself (only), and no
>   bearer of burdens shall bear the burden of another..."[(Surah An'am, Verse 164)](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=6&verse=164) Mohsin Khan

Answer (score -1):

Well for your first question, you won't be committing a sin because its not your fault, you don't know what the intention of the person is to use the radio,
and for the second one, same answer. You don't know their intention. As long as your intention is good you are not committing a sin. :)

Comment: Brother, are there any hadees you can cite?

Answer (score -1):

Stuffs which have a possibility of being abused is a different story. It's like selling a TV, and people can watch both good and bad stuff there. So your intention wasn't to make people watch the bad stuff. So what the people are doing isn't your matter, if they do wrong, they will be held responsible, not you. 
Hope this answers your question, like the other brother said similar, you won't be at fault.

Answer (score -1):

making/selling/dealing in things that have a possibility for Haram use.

It's not your intention for them to sinning. My idea is to watch your your buyer if you want to keep it clean, it's not haram intentionally because all of those stuff are halal to begin with.

Comment: As written, this looks more like personal opinion rather than something backed up by actual expertise or research.